# Symfony 2.7 access image outside web directory

Tags: php, twig, symfony-2.7

I read a lot of article about the problem but it seems that there has to be no answer yet to this.

```
So my project directory is like :
+ uploads_dir
+ symfony_proj
    - app
    - bin
    - src
    - vendor
    - web
```

I want to get the image inside the uploads_dir for me to use in my view page

I created twig extension that fetches the roor directory.. but it seems not to read if I put "root_dir"."../../uploads_dir".

Any suggestions ?

Here is the my twig extension part of it:

```
/**
     * @var container
     */
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container){
        $this->container = $container;
    }

public function bannerFilter($filename)
    {
        $file = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'../../uploads_dir'.$filename;

    }
```

Comment: what is the code for your twig extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make the getting of a resource go through a function, this also enables your to do any kind of other checks (like is user logged in, etc).
Create a controller action that processes the request, and then in your twig you can just use a normal `path()` function.
Some sample code;
parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../../uploads_dir'
```

Sample function;

```
public function getFileAction($file_name)
{
    $base_path = $this->container->getParameter('upload_destination');
    $full_path = $base_path . '/' . $file_name;

    $fs = new FileSystem();
    if (!$fs->exists($full_path)) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException();
    }

    $file_name = basename($full_path);
    $mime_type = $this->getMimeType($full_path);

    $file = readfile($full_path);
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type'     => $mime_type,
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
    return new Response($file, 200, $headers);
}

protected function getMimeType($file)
{
    if ('jpg' === substr($file, -3)) {
        $best_guess = 'jpeg';
    } else {
        $guesser = MimeTypeGuesser::getInstance();
        $best_guess = $guesser->guess($file);
    }

    return $best_guess;

}
```

In your twig;

```
<img src="{{ path('whatever_you_called_your_route', {'file_name': 'my_file.jpg'}) }}" />
```

Comment: it didnt work. When i see page source .. the src starts with app_dev.php/uploads_dir.. but the uploads dir is outside the symfony application.. it should be the same level with symfony app.. symfony app and uploads folder is at the same level.. Thanks for helping @Rooneyl

Comment: the src of the image tag will have the environment, it is a link to a controller action. The image src displayed in the html is the controller action which gets the file, if the upload_destination is wrong change it to your neeeds (it could be an absolute system path).

Comment: I got it working somehow your code helped... But I totally got reference from my other developers code in the current project im working on.. but thanks anyway.. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I got passed this by using `/uploads_dir/`.
I hopes this helps.

Comment: uploads_dir ? @drevanTonder

Comment: I was struggling getting avatar images in lower directories until I used a / in front. don't actually know why it works.

Comment: it seems not related. but anyway how did you right you img src.. that might help

Comment: `$target_dir = '/profile_images/';` when I had a upload script in lower directory.

Comment: I think:: your idea would work if the website is on a server.. but locally that might not work... but thanks anyway for your suggestion ... I got it working using streaming